# What approach would you choose to defend againt DDoS attacks from Nginx level?

Tags: ddos, nginx

I use Nginx compiled with the [Naxsi module](https://github.com/nbs-system/naxsi) to protect against some vulnerabilities (SQL injection and cross-site scripting). Now I need to apply a layer of poor man's DDoS protection at this level.

I read a lot to come to the conclusion that there are three recommended approaches: two modules for Nginx and the option to use a TCP/HTTP load balancer (like HAProxy). The modules I'm referring to are [testcookie](http://kyprizel.github.io/testcookie-nginx-module/) and [anddos](https://github.com/aufi/anddos). Apparently, you can [combine the power of both](https://gist.github.com/ilyaevseev/7503533/raw/5415181364ded61bd4bef189b741d54d90b39990/nginx-stable-antiddos.patch).

What would you recommend not only from a security perspective but also considering the performance point of view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would also recommend using:

- [ngx_http_limit_req_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) to limit RPS, and fallback to 503 on burst cap hit optionally. It does very well with exploited zombie browsers DDoS;
- agressive caching for anonymous users (with next bullet applied maybe) and for target location (in case it is not random) to eliminate FastCGI passes;
- use power of [LUA module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule) and bash-fu to integrate with iptables, to block zombies on a system level to prevent concurrent UDP/SSH/whatever-flood (you may consider using [ipset utility](http://ipset.netfilter.org/) to handle large sets of zombie IPs which iptables will fail to process fast enough).

Comment: Why lua and bash-fu when [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) already exists?

Comment: @Shadur because with LUA-fu one can evaluate more complex ban conditions and filters realtime. Like cookies, additional headers, and maybe some aggregated stats from memcached/redis/RDBMS/etc. fail2ban is quite handy too, but it is not as flexible as nginx+LUA.

Comment: @НЛО: what approach would you suggest "to block zombies on a system level to prevent concurrent UDP/SSH/whatever-flood"?

Comment: @thatguyfromoverthere temporarily block zombie IPs with a firewall as a prevention of some other types of attacks.

Answer (score 0):

i  only know of [Roboo](https://github.com/yuri-gushin/Roboo), which seems to be the forerunner of the testcookie-thingie. 
it is not so easy to detect AND protect from ddos on http-level, esp. on high-volume-sites.

if possible you might want to enable proxy_cache which is quite fast. when you're under attack it is possible to gibve a short cache_time like 1 minute.